# Nginx, Pairing Client and Upstream Ports

Tags: nginx

I wonder if there is a simple way (simple = nginx conf without any lua/perl extension) to achieve the following.

Given the following upstream server and listeners:

```
upstream backend{
    server 1.2.3.4:9080;
    server 1.2.3.4:9081;
    server 1.2.3.4:9082;
}


server {
    listen 8080;
    listen 8081;
    listen 8082;
    ...
    proxy_pass backend;
}
```

The requirement is that all traffic that is connected to a given port, will be passed via `proxy_pass` to the equivalent port at upstream.

Perhaps the `upstream` would not be used in this case, rather I shall use `$http_port` or similar, any advise will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: `ngx_http_upstream_module` isn't designed this way.

While it's possible by using ["route method" for session affinity](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky), such approach will bring you to **very unclear** config.

Consider using multiple `server` blocks. Something like:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:9080;
    }
}
server {
    listen 8081;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:9081;
    }
}
# ...and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have ended up with was using Lua to set a variable (`upstream_port`) which then used as:

```
proxy_pass http://$upstream_host:$upstream_port$request_uri
```